# Update Oracle catalogue views and tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

is it possible to update a table from Oracle catalogue having the appropriate permissions? 
I've read multiple times that it's the DBMS who should modify that tables by itself, but is it possible anyway?

I mean, doing something like this:

```
update all_tables
    set tablespace_name = 'whatever'
    where owner = 'whoever'
    and backed_up = 'Y'
```

Comment: Build yourself a database, grant yourself all the permissions you want, and have at.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even **think** about it. Data dictionary is maintained by Oracle, and if you interfere with it you'll screw up the database and say goodbye. Oracle will deny support and all the blame for damage will be on you.

If you have to do *something*, do it regularly. Otherwise, don't touch it.

Comment: Yes, I know and I don't even have intention to try it out, but it's just a theory question.Would it be possible?

Comment: Don't ask this question - it's a waste of resources. For sure there is so much left you could still learn about Oracle.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to learn al about Oracle catalogue and I think it's a normal question for a person with an intermediate level. I think everyone knows that it's such a bad practice, I'm just asking about the possibility. I don't consider it a waste of resources, excuse me.

Comment: If you ask me, I really wouldn't know, I never tried it. But, if you have a database to spare, try it. Even if you destroy it, no problem as it is created for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Table space name is the one crated by default or can be created by DBA's when where is a requirement. But updating the Oracle metadata is not correct way and you should not be doing it which leads to a conflict.

Comment: Yes, I know and I don't even have intention to try it out, but it's just a theory question.Would it be possible?

Comment: No its not possible. And you should not do it as well even if possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes technically this is possible to do: this is what database creation, upgrade and sometimes database patching does. You can find a lot of SQL scripts in `ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin`  that are doing this.

But as already said this is something you should never do unless being told by Oracle support.

If you want to understand how the database dictionary is created from scratch see `catalog.sql` created 32 years ago: `Rem   Grayson    03/21/88 - Creation`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, what a simple question and how many upset answers!

Yes, technically you can change Oracle's data dictionary tables, and no, you'r not supposed to, but I do understand your curiosity. It's ok to look under the hood, just use a database from for instance [here](https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-boxes), play around and throw it away.

You won't be able to change the datadictionary views like `ALL_TABLES` directly, because they are views on top tables like `SYS.TAB$`. (The definition is visible in `DBA_VIEWS.TEXT`). If you want to see the `CREATE` statements of them, they are on the database server at `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin` and actually quite interesting.

The silliest thing I've seen on the internet was somebody who inserted a second 'X' into the table `DUAL`. Please don't do that at home!

I am rather sure that it is possible to alter those SYS tables, but I would never ever do it, because they will become inconsistent. If you think about it, it's the store used by Oracle to guarantee the integrity of your tables, so the integrity of the store itself cannot fully be protected. You insert a row into `SYS.COL$`, but that doesn't mean that your table has got a new column, just the dictionary's information is wrong.